# FB App Timeline : number of readers who read (action) an article (object)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

In a Facebook Timeline App, so a facebook app that use OG 2.0, 
I want to display the number of users that read the article like this: "Read by 115 people".

And i want to get all possible information about my article (object).

Thanks.